# move multiple directories in one directory - recursively

Tags: directory, mv, move

I have a directory which contains multiple directories including subdirectories too. I want to move some of them to a single one at the same time (with one command)

Example

```
Main Directory
     Sub1
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Sub2
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Sub3
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Sub4
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Sub5
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Test
 -----------------------
```

I want to move Sub1, Sub2, Sub3 including their subdirectories, into Test folder, so finally I will have something like this

```
Main Directory
     Sub4
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Sub5
        Subsub1
        Subsub2
     Test
         Sub1
             Subsub1
             Subsub2
         Sub2
             Subsub1
             Subsub2
         Sub3
             Subsub1
             Subsub2
 -----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `"Main Directory"/Test` exists:

```
mv "Main Directory"/Sub[1-3] "Main Directory"/Test
```

The only thing happening here is that you move the directories into the `Test` directory.  The files in `Sub1`, `Sub2` and `Sub3` will still be available in those same directories, but now under the new path `"Main Directory"/Test/Sub1` etc.

---

With updated information in the comments below, assuming `bash` is used as the shell:

```
mkdir -p "Main Directory"/Test
mv "Main Directory"/episode_{0000..0049} "Main Directory"/Test
```

The brace expansion `"Main Directory"/episode_{0000..0049}` would expand to `Main Directory/episode_0000 Main Directory/episode_0001` ... `Main Directory/episode_0049`.

Comment: when doing it in one line as Sub[1-3] , it gives me No such file or directory

Comment: @MostafaHussein Then you are either not executing the command from the directory containing `"Main Directory"`, or your subdirectories have different names not matching the pattern`Sub[1-3]`.

Comment: my subdirectories are like that: episode_0000 till episode_0049
I want to move episode_0000 till episode_0039 to another directory

Comment: @MostafaHussein It would have been helpful if you had stated that in the question from the start.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't have the folders ready, I was just getting the idea, then I created these folders

Comment: @MostafaHussein See updated answer.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot @Kusalananda and sorry for the conflict

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this using `-t` flag with the `mv` command.

The syntax would look like the following.

```bsh
mv -t <destination> <src1> <src2> .... <srnN>
```

You can do that in the reverse fashion as well:

```bsh
mv file1 file2 file3 -t DESTINATION
```

In your case will be:

```bsh
mv -t Test/ Sub1/ Sub2/ Sub3/
```

Source: [DevopsCube](https://discuss.devopscube.com/t/how-to-move-mv-multiple-directories-or-files-to-a-folder-at-a-time/100) / [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097781/how-to-move-multiple-folders-to-another-directory)

Answer (score 1):

you can specify using curly braces,

```
mv {Sub1, Sub2, Sub3} Test/
```

Comment: Did you test this?  The result will probably surprise you.

Comment: @Kusalananda I did test it it works - but to make sure: could you elaborate?

Comment: @InsOp It would move the files `{Sub1,`, `Sub2,`, and `Sub3}` to the directory `Test`. It's not actually a brace expansion.